# question number reordering

Tags: javascript

I have a list of question in my javascript file. Each question has a question number and question description and options. A question can be added anywhere in the list of questions. So if a question is added into the top of all questions, then i need to change the question numbers of all the below ones. How can achieve this. Can i use javascript for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an `<ol>` for each question, and let the page handle reflowing the numbers.

Otherwise you'll need to set a target number before inserting, and for each element in the list you'll check to see if it's number is greater than the target, and then if so increment the number by one.

```
var Target = //new number that I want the inserted question to be
foreach (element in list) {
  if (element.Number > Target) element.Number += 1;
}
list.add( //new question with # set to Target );
```

Comment: thank u.. but i didnt understand what you meant by page handle reflowing the numbers

Comment: @Rohan Have you ever seen an <ol> in action? visit this page http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists and add some elements on the left.

Comment: @Toader ... did I forget my indents? /facepalm

Comment: @Toader happens to us all at some point ... ah well ~ and thanks for the catch ;)

Answer (score 1):

This works.

`<ol id="questions_list"></ol>`

```
var questions = ["A foo walks into a bar. What happens?", "Why did foo cross the road?"];  

addQuestion("foo", 1);
function addQuestion(question, position)
{
    if(position > 0 && position < questions.length)
    {
        var firstHalf = questions.slice(0, position);
        var secondHalf = questions.slice(position, questions.length);
        firstHalf.push(question);
        questions = firstHalf.concat(secondHalf);
        console.log("slice");
    }else if(position <= 0)
    {
        questions.unshift(question);
        console.log("beginning");  
    }else if(position >= questions.length)
    {
        questions.push(question);
        console.log("end");
    }
    updateQuestionList();
}

function updateQuestionList()
{
    var questions_list = document.getElementById("questions_list");
    questions_list.innerHTML = "";
    for(var i=0;i<questions.length;i++)
    {
        var question = document.createElement("LI");
        question.innerHTML = questions[i];
        questions_list.appendChild(question);
    } 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jPxwW/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using ordered lists (ol) and jQuery:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript">
$(function(){

  var n = 2;

  $('button').delegate('click', function(){
    $(this).parents('li').after('<li><p><span>Question'+n+'</span><button>Create new question</button></p></li>');
    n += 1;
  })

})
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <p><span>Question 1</span><button>Create new question</button></p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Array prototype ( fun! =) ):

```
// zero-based insert
Array.prototype.insert = function(index, item) {
    var i = 0, list = [];

    if (this.length == index) {
        list = this;
        list.push(item);
        return list;
    }

    for(; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (index == list.length) {
            list.push(item);
            i--;
        } else {
            list.push(this[i]);
        }
    }

    return list;
};

Array.prototype.print = function (base) {
    base = base || 1;
    for (var i = 0, out = []; i < this.length; i++) {
        out.push((base + i) + '. ' + this[i]);
    }

    return out.join("\n");
};


list = ['when?', 'where?', 'why?'];
list = list.insert(0, 'who?'); // first: ["who?", "when?", "where?", "why?"]
list = list.insert(3, 'how?'); // 4th: ["who?", "when?", "where?", "how?", "why?"]
list = list.insert(list.length, 'last?'); // last: ["who?", "when?", "where?", "how?", "why?", "last?"];

list.print();
/**
"1. who?
 2. when?
 3. where?
 4. how?
 5. why?
 6. last?"
 **/
```